# Why can't I plot a recursively defined function without first expanding it?

Tags: plotting, recursion

I have a recursively-defined sequence of functions, g[t,n], that I cannot seem to plot without first evaluating and then referencing the result.  What do I need to do to g to get it to plot correctly?

[image: Mathematica Example]

Comment: Post your code not image.

Comment: Try this `Plot[Evaluate@g[t, 1], {t, 0, 4}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g[t_, 0] := -9.8*t^2 + 10

s[n_] := u /. Solve[g[u, n - 1] == 0, u][[2]]

v[n_] := D[g[t, n - 1], t] /. (t -> s[n])

g[t_, n_] := -9.8*(t - s[n])^2 - v[n]/2*(t - s[n])

Plot[Evaluate@g[t, 1], {t, 0, 4}]
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  This works.  What is the underlying issue though?

Comment: Try evaluating `Block[{t = 0.1}, g[t, 1]]` vs `Block[{t = 0.1}, Evaluate @ g[t, 1]]`